# how to call a sub from a different slide in vba powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

working in PowerPoint, I need to call a sub from a different slide. For example, I'm creating a macro that is located in one slide, and refers to a sub in another slide, for example:

```
**Slide 3:**

Sub Login()
If Slide3.LoginBox.Text = Slide1.CreatePasswordLogin.Text Then
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
    Slide3.LoginBox.Text = ""
    Call LoginShapeLoad (the one from slide 4 for example)
Else
    MsgBox "Incorrect Password!", vbExclamation, "Login Prompt"
    Slide3.LoginBox.Text = ""
End If
End Sub


**Slide 4:**

Sub LoginShapeLoad()
If Shapes("Shape1").Visible Then
Else
    Shapes("Shape1").ZOrder msoBringToFront
        Shapes("Shape1").Visible = msoTrue
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: anyone? I'm hoping for an answer today tbh

Comment: Are you getting an error then or something? You did not state any specific problem.

Comment: @bruhmoment I've made a very simple test in a new module with 2 routines called `Slide1` and `Slide2`. All `Slide1` does is `Call Slide2` which prints the name of a default shape into the *immediate* window. This executes successfully. Please edit your question to include some detail around the issue you have with your code.

Comment: Of course/at least `"Shape1"` must exist on slide 3.

Answer (score 0):

Add a module to your VBA project and put this code there. You can then call it from anywhere else.

```
Public Sub LoginShapeLoad()

With ActivePresentation.Shapes("Shape1")
  If Not .Visible Then
    .ZOrder msoBringToFront
    .Visible = msoTrue
  End If
End With

End Sub
```

Or to make it more generically useful:

```
Public Sub LoginShapeLoad(oSh as Shape)

With oSh
  If Not .Visible Then
    .ZOrder msoBringToFront
    .Visible = msoTrue
  End If
End With

End Sub
```

And invoke it with something like this:

```
Sub MakeAnyShapeVisible()
  Dim oSh as Shape

  ' Change 42 to the slide number, SomeName to the shape name
  ' you want to make visible:
  Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(42).Shapes("SomeName")

  Call LogInShapeLoad(oSh)

End Sub
```